# Visual Studio : Macro to Generate Custom Comments (Code Snippet)

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to generate such a formatted head comment with a shortcut

```
//##########################################################
//                    METHOD-NAME-HERE
//##########################################################
public static IShouldBeSleepingAtThisTime(DateTime veryLate)
{        
   ForceStopCoding();
   CallGFToApologize(veryLate);
   GoBackHome();  
}
```

Ideally I would like to override/customize the triple-slash generate-comments behaviour to inset '#' lines and other info, As this improves code readability for large classes.

EDIT : 
In addition to TheChrisKent's very useful snippet, found a quick little Tuto by Agafonov Viacheslav on how to integrate that easily into VS [HERE](http://blog.agafonov.net.ua/post/2010/11/27/Visual-Studio-2010-code-snippets.aspx)

Comment: No idea how to answer but +1 for the code snippet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an xml file with the extension .snippet and place this inside:

```
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <Header>
    <Title>OglethorpeComments</Title>
    <Author>Mika Jacobi</Author>
    <Shortcut>ogle</Shortcut>
    <Description>pretty comments with #</Description>
    <SnippetTypes>
      <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
    </SnippetTypes>
  </Header>
  <Snippet>
    <Declarations>
      <Literal>
        <ID>Method</ID>
        <Default>Method-Name-Here</Default>
      </Literal>
    </Declarations>
    <Code Language="CSharp">
      <![CDATA[//##########################################################
//                    $Method$
//##########################################################]]>
    </Code>
  </Snippet>
</CodeSnippet>
```

Then follow the remaining directions here: http://www.visualstudiotutor.com/2010/02/create-snippet-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Rock'N'Roll. That was sweet. Thanks, buddie !

Answer (score 0):

You may create a visual studio code snippet, watch [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share what I did. I created a snippet, in the header section, I added a shortcut tag.

```
<Shortcut>---</Shortcut>
```

Now I can type "---" and press tab and my comment snippet appears.